# Mobile browser 'Files and media' permission status

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser

My problem is quite simple.

I have a simple input for files (especially images) in a page.

```html
<input type='file' accept='image/*'/>
```

When a **mobile** user browses the page from, let's say Chrome, if he previously denied the permission to access "Files and media", if the user clicks on the input, nothing happens.

This is quite annoying for the user experience. I do understand that I can't bypass the security, although, it would be really cool to be able to check the permission, at least, to explain to the user what he needs to do in order to use the feature.

I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query but the list of permissions does not contain anything related to the "Files and media" permission...

Is there anyway to check this permission? To be able to prompt the user for it would be great, but at least, my priority is to know what is the permission's status from JavaScript to explain to the user why it does nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: I removed storage permission for chrome and then tried to click on a input[type="file"] element. The browser automatically prompts me *Allow chrome to access photos, media, contents and files on your device*. If I again deny this permission here and click input element again it'll again ask for permission.

Comment: Maybe in another version there was a 'dont ask again'?

Comment: I'm on last version of Android (Pixel phone) with last version of Chrome, and there are three modes "allowed", "ask every time" and "denied". When it is on denied, no way to get a prompt or a return from the system :( I assume it can vary depending on the Android version + manufacturer mod... So the best would really be to be able to determine the permission status via JS, and let the user tweak his phone if necessary.

Comment: @sjahan, I found there is a "don't ask again' checkbox after checking it never prompt me. I have found this similar question: [Android - check from web site if Chrome app has storage permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153240/android-check-from-web-site-if-chrome-app-has-storage-permission)

Comment: Pretty bad solution of the Chrome programmers. I would fire such people if nothing happens when a user presses a button. ;-).

Comment: That's definitely a shame, I'll let this post run some time, but I feel like i'll end up adding a panel like "Dear user, if nothing happens when you click on the button, please check your browser's permissions". What really disturbs me is that I am able to have the status of the camera for instance, but not the access to file system :( That seems really crappy... Not even something thrown in the console...